# File locking a socket?

Tags: c++, c, posix

Is it possible to lock a socket for a thread? For example using `flock`?

These locks are designed for files, but they take a generic file descriptor as a parameter.

Comment: Have you considered std::mutex ?

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs I have. This socket goes through several layers of the software stack. Introducing a mutex would require a modification of a big chunk of the software, including some of the external API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation specifically states that flock is meant for files. From the MacOS documentation page (man): (emphasis added)

> Flock() applies or removes an advisory lock on the **file** associated with the file descriptor fd.

In particular, this is meant for inter-process synchronization on the same *file*. Assuming that you are trying to lock amongst threads within a process, it seems wise to instead rely on pthread_mutex_lock/unlock. (You are about to do a slow IO, so I woulnd't bother with spinlocks either).

Hope that helps,

Comment: From the same man pages under NOTES:  "Locks are on files, not file descriptors."